# Angular 6 ngFor referencing loop variable in same parent element

Tags: angular

I have an Angular Material accordion I wish to create using an *ngFor as follows -

```
<mat-expansion-panel class="noShadow border-top"
                     [expanded]="guest.get('expanded').value"
                     [formGroup]="guest"
                     *ngFor="let guest of guestFormArr.controls; let i = index;">
```

Please take note of the [expanded] attribute whereby I need to set it according to the 'guest' variable from the *ngFor loop.

I can't seem to get this to work. Is this even possible? Can an element access the 'guest' variable at the same level it is defined? I understand the nested elements accessing 'guest'.

Thank you

**SOLUTION:**

I ended up doing the following

```
<mat-expansion-panel class="noShadow border-top"
                 *ngFor="let guest of guestFormArr.controls; let i = index;"
                 [formGroup]="guest" [expanded]="open === i">
```

I would then simply increase or decrease the 'open' variable on the 'Next' and 'Back' buttons which had (click)=next(i) or (click)=back(i) respectively.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Order matters, set `expanded` and `formGroup` property after the `*ngFor`. Currently, you are trying to set those properties before initializing `guest` variable so it will be `undefined`.

```
<mat-expansion-panel class="noShadow border-top"
                     *ngFor="let guest of guestFormArr.controls; let i = index;"
                     [formGroup]="guest"
                     [expanded]="guest.get('expanded').value">
```

Comment: I am going to accept this answer as it was correct even though I ended up using a different solution. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are using `guest` before you declare it. To fix it just change the order of attributes it should work then.

Put the `*ngFor` before all attribute that uses `guest`.

```
<mat-expansion-panel class="noShadow border-top"
                     *ngFor="let guest of guestFormArr.controls; let i = index;"
                     [expanded]="guest.get('expanded').value"
                     [formGroup]="guest">
```